# how do I access information from files in subdirectories with os.walk?

Tags: python

I want to access and process information from files in sub-directories from a root directory. I have tried using os.walk, which gets me to the files, but how do I access their contents? I want specific files in these sub-directories that all have the same name, but there are other files in these sub-directories. This is what I have tried:

```
import os
import numpy as np
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/rootDir/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('sum.txt')):
            print file  #Here, the desired file name is printed
            PIs = []
            for line in file:
                print line #Here, I only get 's' printed, which I believe is the first letter in 'sum.txt'
                line = line.rstrip()
                line = line.split('\t')
                PIs.append(line[2])
    print PIs #nothing is collected so nothing is printed
```

How do I loop over the lines in the desired files in these sub-directories in the root directory?

ADDED PROBLEM:

I got the answer to my first question, now I have another. In the directories under the root there are many sub-directories. I want to access information from only one sub-directory that has the same name in all directories. This is what I tried:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/rootPath/"):
  for dname in dirs:
    #print dname, type(dname)
    allPIs = []
    allDirs = []
    if dname.endswith('code_output'):  #I only want to access information from one file in sub-directories with this name
      ofh = open("sumPIs.txt", 'w')
      ofh.write("path\tPIs_mean\n")
      for fname in files: #Here i want to be in the code_output sub-directory
        print fname #here I only want to see files in the sub-directory with the 'code_output' end of a name, but I get all files in the directory AND sub-directory
        if fname.endswith('sumAll.txt'):
          PIs = []
          with open(os.path.join(root,fname), 'r') as fh_in:
            for line in fh_in:
              line = line.rstrip()
              line = line.split('\t')
              PIs.append(int(line[2]))
          PIs_mean = numpy.mean(PIs)
          allPIs.append(PIs_mean)
          allDirs.append(filePath)
```

Why does this loop over ALL files in the directory and not only the sub-directory with the name ending 'code_output'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `with` context handler to open the file handles. The file handle is closed when you exit the `with` block, so you don't accidentally leave lots of file handles open.

Also `file` is a built in class in Python so probably best not use that as the name of a variable.

```
import os
PIs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/rootDir/"):
  for fname in files:
    if fname.endswith('sum.txt'):
      print fname  #Here, the wanted file name is printed
      with open(os.path.join(root,fname), 'r') as fh_in:
        for line in fh_in:
          print line # here I only get 's' printed, which I believe is the first letter in 'sum.txt'
          line = line.rstrip()
          line = line.split('\t')
          PIs.append(line[2])
print PIs #nothing is collected so nothing is printed
```

Comment: I'd put `PIs=[]` out of the for loop :P

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes indeed

Comment: You need to os.path.join(root,fname). fname is only the basename of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try not use keywords for variable names `file`. Use f, file_, etc ...

`file` is a string change the line

```
for line in file_
```

by

```
for line in open(file_).readlines()
```

Comment: I think it is __in__. And __file__ is keyword

Comment: Yeah, I use `file` to keep the code as similar as the original. but you're right about `in`